# I want to split the string stored in a variable and store the obtained values in variable using xslt

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

```
<xsl:variable name="AAM" select="//AAM"/>
```

AAM will have string `value_1,value_2,value_3,value_4`
I then want to split this and store in 4 variables :

seg1,
seg2,
seg3,
seg4

Comment: Please show the input XML, it is not clear whether you have a single `AAM` element or several ones. Creating four variables only makes sense if you know the input has four values.What is supposed to happen if there are more than four values?

Comment: AAM values is restricted to have 4 vales ,i taking this value from cookie and storing this in AAM varible.I want to slipt this value n store in 4 variables @MartinHonnen

Comment: If it is restricted to have 4 values, then 4 separate variables can be created with your given (hard-coded) variable names.

Comment: MAX is 4 it can be 1 ,2 or all 4 .so depending on that i need to set the variable name and value too @MartinHonnen

Comment: Well, I doubt the variables will be useful because they would be scoped limited. Though I have added one more solution to meet your requirement.

Comment: Please select either XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0 - not both. If it's XSLT 1.0, tell us which processor you'll be using, so that we know which extensions you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the below as your input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
     <AAM>value_1,value_2,value_3,value_4</AAM>
</body>
```

An **XSLT 2.0** solution to split a **comma separated string** can be:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:variable name="AAM" select="//AAM" />

<xsl:template match="body">
    <body>
        <xsl:variable name="separator" select="','" />
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($AAM,$separator)">
            <xsl:element name="seg{position()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </body>
</xsl:template>
```

http://xsltransform.net/6qaFCET/1

**Edit:** (Based on commented)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:variable name="AAM" select="//AAM" />

<xsl:template match="body">
    <body>
        <xsl:variable name="separator" select="','" />
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($AAM,$separator)">

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
                    <xsl:variable name="seg1">
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$seg1" />
                    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="position() = 2">
                    <xsl:variable name="seg2">
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$seg2" />
                    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="position() = 3">
                    <xsl:variable name="seg3">
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$seg3" />
                    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="position() = 4">
                    <xsl:variable name="seg4">
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$seg4" />
                    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </body>
</xsl:template>
```

http://xsltransform.net/6qaFCET/2

**Note:** following lines can be avoided. It has been added to populate value of variables.

`<xsl:copy-of select="$seg2" />
 <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>`

Comment: <xsl:variable name="AAM" select="//AAM"> this have declared in same xsl file i want to read this variable value to test some condition @Vebbie

Comment: A well-formed input is required to answer exactly as expected. Though, I have tried to create a global variable based on your question. You can check if it fulfills your queries. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: <xsl:element name="seg{position()}"> <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" /> </xsl:element> instead of creating here element i want to store this to variables @Vebbie

Comment: what about version 1.0?if i want the same result @Vebbie

Comment: In **XSLT 1.0**, there is no `tokenize` function. there will be more overhead of writing templates to split the string. Nothing will be change in logic of storing the values in variables.

Comment: have used substring-before(concat($text, $separator), $separator) function but want to storer these in variables based on the index @Vebbie

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `<AAM>value_1,value_2,value_3,value_4</AAM>` and `<xsl:variable name="AAM" select="//AAM"/>` you can of course use e.g. `<xsl:variable name="value-sequence" select="tokenize($AAM, ',')"/>` and if then needed access e.g. `$value-sequence[1]`, `$value-sequence[2]` and so on, thus if you know there are only four values you can declare `<xsl:variable name="seq1" select="$value-sequence[1]"/>`, `<xsl:variable name="seq2" select="$value-sequence[2]"/>` and so on. The `tokenize` function is part of XPath 2 and later so works with XSLT 2 or 3 processors like Saxon 9 or AltovaXML or XmlPrime.

Answer (score 0):

Answering late.
Maybe this is not an exact solution. But this may help you.
This is how I'm able to split a string from an XML node into two variables using XSLT 1.0

```
<xsl:when test="NodeName">
<xsl:variable name="var" select="NodeName"/>
<xsl:variable name="var1" select="substring-before($var, '=')"/>
<xsl:variable name="var2" select="substring-after($var, '=')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$var1"/>-
<xsl:value-of select="$var2"/>
</xsl:when>
```

For Further reference [Click Here](https://www.oxygenxml.com/forum/xslt-and-fop/topic10355.html)